# ¿Puedo obtener resultados de las Asyntask que se ejecutan en otra AsynTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

El problema es el siguiente:
en el app que desarrollo, llego a un punto que tengo que exportar todos los registros almacenados localmente a un webservice(lo cual ya se ejecuta),pero busco la manera de obtener el resultado de cada asyntask ejecutada en tiempo real, el resultado es un contador de que registros se actualizaron, generaron y cuales son los que no se pudo hacer ninguna de las dos anteriores;

alguna sugerencia se los agradeceria

Comment: al obtener los resultados en onPostExecute() los deseas visualizar en un TextView o que elemento? si son varios AsyncTask deseas se visualicen en el mismo elemnto o en varios?

Comment: deseo que en un progresdialog se visualicen Agregados: 2, Actualizados 2, Error: 1, como ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

Según entiendo tu problema.
Sólo necesitas actualizar el valor de cada una de tus variables para las progresbar en cada resultado de asynckTask y llamar una función que te actualice las progresbar de acuerdo al valor de cada variable.

Comment: Eso deberia ser un comentario no una respuesta

Comment: si asi es amigo... concuerdo con el comentario del colega.... una idea o comentario,  tengo 3 meses desarrollando en android y aun no entiendo mucho de como trabaja

Comment: @Webserveis es una respuesta. Quizás no sea de la calidad esperada pero es una respuesta. Si estás en contra, puedes votar en negativo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el metódo `publishProgress` para mandar desde el `doInBackground()` información cada vez que se ejecute una acción y puedas actualizar la UI desde el hilo principal implementando el metodo `onProgressUpdate()` ya sea en un `progressDialog` o cualquier componente de la iterfaz que utilices para mostrar el progreso de la tarea.

Answer (score 0):

Al responderte esta pregunta lo hago con una duda en mente: ¿Porqué en otra `AsyncTask`?

Supongo el siguiente escenario: a través de un evento (de usuario o de aplicación) se ejecuta un export de tus datos locales hacia un servicio web. Con esto pueden pasar algunas cosas:

1. Todos los registros se exportan correctamente, pero en este caso tienes items que pueden actualizarse y crearse
2. Algunos registros no se procesaron correctamente
3. Ningún registro se procesó correctamente

Lo primero que debes tener presente, es que esa información (quien falló, quien se procesó correctamente) te la debe dar el servicio web, ya que es la aplicación web quien conoce de primera mano el resultado de sus procesos internos.

Por lo que, a mi parecer; tienes 2 opciones:

1. **Procesar registros uno a uno**: esto para nada es óptimo, pero resolvería tu necesidad de *informar en tiempo real*, no es optimo porque para cada registro el servidor web deberá enviarte una respuesta sobre el estado de cada item, lo que a nivel de concurrencia se transforma en un lío; porque por cuestiones de conectividad ningún envío se realiza en una taza de tiempo fijo y tambien va a depender de como manejes los procesos que realizan los envíos.
2. **Procesar por lotes**: Para mí es mejor que ejecutes una sola llamada a proceso en un `AsynTask`, `Thread`, `Runnable` (como gustes) y que internamente el servicio web *genere un resumen* que es el que vas a mostrar al usuario; mientras que en tu aplicación móvil mostrarías el usual mensaje de que se está realizando un trabajo pesado y que tomará su tiempo (dependiendo de cuantos registros sean)

Ten en cuenta que realizar una llamada HTTP es costoso en función del tiempo que toma conectarse si es que el canal de conexión no es óptimo (ancho de banda responsable), tampoco dejes de tener presente la capacidad de tu servidor web si es que la cantidad de clientes móviles es considerablemente grande, esto puede causarte indisponibilidad de tu servicio principal.